# should I use dart sdk bundled with flutter for things other than flutter?

Tags: windows, flutter, dart, sdk

Say, I have installed the latest flutter sdk that has a dart sdk bundled with it. After adding necessary path 'flutter-sdk/bin' to environment variables, I am able to use both dart and flutter commands. Now, assume I wanted to start using dart for backend development and do not want to do anything with flutter. Should I install dart sdk separately for this purpose? If I do install it separately, will flutter use it or will flutter use its bundled version only. How can I really have Dart SDK and Flutter SDK installed together without having conflicting binaries. Any help would be appreciated. Additionally, I am on Windows 11. I did some research on this question, and apparently, this doubt hasn't been answered as far as searching it up is concerned.

TL;DR I am looking for a way to install Full Dart SDK alongside Flutter SDK and I am asking is it safe to do so and what sdk should have priority in environment path order.

> *I have followed the stackoverflow guidelines and this questions is legal.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It is safe to install official full dart sdk alongside flutter sdk. Flutter will actually only use the bundled sdk and that ofcourse can be configured. No conflicting behavious is expected in doing so.